# Overriding predefined model method : "delete()"

Tags: django, model

I have this model:

```
class MedicoImage(models.Model): 
        medico          = models.ForeignKey(Medico)
        imagem          = models.ImageField(max_length=300,upload_to='img_medico')
```

I want to delete image file always the object data base was deleted.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog post](http://haineault.com/blog/147/) has a nice summary of the issue and possible workarounds.

The gist is that Django intentionally changed `FileField` handling in 1.2.5, such that the associated files are *not* removed when the object is deleted, for security reasons.